# Creating export of records from one database to another

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I have a staging db with new changes, now I want to make these changes to live db. 
My specific requirements :

1) Fetch all the data from the parent table (Id will be passed by user)

2) Fetch all the child tables data based on the parent id.

3) Check if that record is present on live.

- If record is not present, insert as new
- If record is already present, keep the id's intact and update only the data.

Below is the approach I am trying to do. I created two connections for staging and live db's, I fetched the data in php objects, Now I am trying to compare each key/value and will create an insert/update based on the distinct values and will exclude the duplicates.

For this, I am thinking of using the Reflection API, (Comparing each value of the object)
Also looked upon few already given answers related to this :
[Laravel 4.2: Copying database records from one database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083101/laravel-4-2-copying-database-records-from-one-database-to-another)

Please guide me if there is some faster/better solution. (Like using Seeders, Eloquent, etc)

Comment: I had the similar case in past where we were having replication server and master server but sometime due to synchronization issue the records in master and slave tables were mismatched. And our reporting from slave server were going wrong. So I used perconna toolkit, it checks source table and destination table and sync the chages to destination table. It would be quiet tricky to write own script. Better use percona toolkit - https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html

Comment: Ok, but this will sync all the data from staging to master, I want only specific data from staging to be pushed to live db